# How can I add a WHERE clause for each row in a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `content` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tag_a_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_b_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_c_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_d_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_e_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` varchar(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

The `tags` table has a one-to-many relationship with the content table, using the `tag_?_id` fields, but each tag ID will only appear ONCE per row.

I would like to do a query in which I select all rows from the `content` table that are associated with a given set of tags (and all tags associated). For example, "get me all content rows that have the tags "News" and "MedicalCare" associated.

This means the IDs for "News" and "MedicalCare" need to be looked up in the `tags` table, and then injected into a query on the `content` table, using a pair of queries like this (assuming those tags have the IDs `45` and `68`):

```
SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag IN ("News","MedicalCare");
```

... and then...

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.content, ts_a.tag, ts_b.tag, ts_c.tag, ts_d.tag, ts_e.tag
FROM (
    SELECT t.id, t.content, t.tag_a_id, t.tag_b_id, t.tag_c_id, t.tag_d_id, t.tag_e_id
    FROM content t
    WHERE 45 IN (t.tag_a_id, t.tag_b_id, t.tag_c_id, t.tag_d_id, t.tag_e_id)
    AND 68 IN (t.tag_a_id, t.tag_b_id, t.tag_c_id, t.tag_d_id, t.tag_e_id)
    ORDER BY t.id ASC LIMIT 200
) t1
LEFT JOIN tags ts_a ON t1.tag_a_id=ts_a.id
LEFT JOIN tags ts_b ON t1.tag_b_id=ts_b.id
LEFT JOIN tags ts_c ON t1.tag_c_id=ts_c.id
LEFT JOIN tags ts_d ON t1.tag_d_id=ts_d.id
LEFT JOIN tags ts_e ON t1.tag_e_id=ts_e.id;
```

Is there a way I can fetch the tag IDs I'm interested in *within* this query, and dynamically generate those AND x IN (a,b,c) clauses?

Another option might be something like:

```
WHERE EVERY ONE OF (
    SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tag IN ("News","MedicalCare")
) IN (t.tag_a_id, t.tag_b_id, t.tag_c_id, t.tag_d_id, t.tag_e_id)
```

PLEASE NOTE: The `content` table is very large, so it is unfeasible to join the content table to the tags table without first filtering out unwanted rows and applying a `LIMIT`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to limit a given content item to have up to 5 tags? What happens if you want more? What happens if 80% of your content items only have 1-2 tags? You might want to consider adding a content-tag table that links to content_id and tag_id.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - this is something I considered in the original design of my database. However, the content table goes into the millions of rows, therefore joins to a many-to-many table in order to filter the results by tag are very expensive.

Comment: Not really.  If it were my db, I'd normalize it.

Comment: Aha... eureka moment. My original query performed a `GROUP BY` before a `LIMIT` on the result of the join between the content and tags tables. It turns out, the `GROUP BY` was the expensive part - I thought it was the join. If I put the query into a subquery and `LIMIT` the rowset there, then do `GROUP BY` on the result of that subquery (now only a maximum of 1000 rows), the query completes about 1000 times faster.

Comment: @Alex. As long as you're correctly indexing your tables, the cost of a simple join like this is minimal. Joining tables on non-indexed columns results in table scans which are slow. Joining on indexed columns should be pretty fast.

Comment: If you had a table "content_tag", you would appreciate the FK index (InnoDB) to tag_id which would automagically filter to you the desired content_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
select t1.id, t1.content, ts_a.tag, ts_b.tag, ts_c.tag, ts_d.tag, ts_e.tag
from content t1
LEFT JOIN tags ts_a ON t1.tag_a_id=ts_a.id
LEFT JOIN tags ts_b ON t1.tag_b_id=ts_b.id
LEFT JOIN tags ts_c ON t1.tag_c_id=ts_c.id
LEFT JOIN tags ts_d ON t1.tag_d_id=ts_d.id
LEFT JOIN tags ts_e ON t1.tag_e_id=ts_e.id
where "News" in (ts_a.tag, ts_b.tag, ts_c.tag, ts_d.tag, ts_e.tag)
and "MedicalCare" in (ts_a.tag, ts_b.tag, ts_c.tag, ts_d.tag, ts_e.tag)
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I agree, I think this would work, but I'm afraid my question initially lacked an important piece of extra information, my apologies - the content table is very large, therefore performing joins before filtering out unwanted rows from the content table is very expensive.

Comment: Accepted this answer after all as it turns out I was mistaken about what the expensive part of my original query was. D'oh.

Comment: I think your original query can also do what you want. Replace the hard-coded 45 and 68 with subqueries, e.g. `WHERE (SELECT id FROM contents ...) IN (tag_a_id, tag_b_id, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the tags are unique, you can do something like:

```
where ((ts_a.tag in ('News', 'MecialCare')) +
       (ts_b.tag in ('News', 'MecialCare')) +
       (ts_c.tag in ('News', 'MecialCare')) +
       (ts_d.tag in ('News', 'MecialCare')) +
       (ts_e.tag in ('News', 'MecialCare'))
      ) = 2
```

This uses the fact that in MySQL a comparison returns 0 or 1, which can then be added together.

By the way, this question is a good reason why data should be properly structured, with a table that would a separate row for each tag for each person, a persno_tag table.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The 5 tag fields in the content table are IDs, which refer to rows in the tags table. If I understand this correctly, I would need to go 5 identical subqueries in place of `('News', 'MedicalCare')`?

Comment: @Alex . . . If fixed the code.  But I also like BarMar's approach.  His uses standard SQL, whereas mine is using a MySQL-specific feature (although I could easily fix this by wrapping everything in a `case` statement).